# How to populate footer in bottom of the table - using PHP drupal 7

Tags: php, foreach, drupal-7, footer

I have function which display images and populate summary of total find of images total directories and total should resolved/ total resolved

But it displaying at the end of page I want to show at the bottom I have also attach screen shot of my values which is displaying at the bottom:

Here is my function:

```
function _network_drive_test(){
$arguments = arg();
$id = $arguments[count($arguments) - 2];

$query = db_select('network_drive_listing','n');
$query
->fields('n')
->condition('n.network_drive_id',$id)
->orderBy('n.ndlistid');
 $results = $query->execute();

 $header = array(t('Sr no'),t('Image'),t('Public Path'), t('Is Dir'),t('Status'));
 $rows = array();
 $totalFind = 0;
 $totalShouldFind = 0;
 $totalIsDir = 0;
 $totalResolved = 0;
 $forOfor = 0;
 foreach($results as $record) {
  $totalFind++;
  $array = [
  $totalFind,
  $record->public_path !== "" ? '<div style="background-image: url(\'' .   url($record->public_path) . '\'); height: 50px; width:50px;background-size: cover;border-radius: 50%;background-position: center;" />' : '',
  $record->public_path,
  $record->is_dir
];
if ($record->is_dir != 1) {
  $totalShouldFind++;
  $headers = @get_headers($record->public_path);

  // Use condition to check the existence of URL
  if ($headers && strpos($headers[0], '200')) {
    $array['status'] = "URL Exist" . PHP_EOL;
    $totalResolved++;
  } else {
    $array['status'] = "URL Doesn't Exist(" . $record->public_path . ")" . PHP_EOL;
    $forOfor++;
  }

  } else {
     $totalIsDir++;
     $array['status'] = "This is directory" . PHP_EOL;
  }
   $rows[] = $array;
 }
  $array = [
  $form['#prefix'] = '<div class="page_summary" <strong>Summary: </strong>',
  $form['#prefix'] = '<div class="total_find" <strong>Total Find: </strong>'. $totalFind,
  $form['#prefix'] = '<div class="total_dir" <strong>Total Find: </strong>'. $totalIsDir,
  $form['#prefix'] = '<div class="total_should_resolve" <strong>Total Should Resolve</strong>: ' . $totalShouldFind.'<strong> / Total Resolved : </strong>'. $totalResolved,
  $form['#prefix'] = '<div class="error_bar" style="display">404:'.$forOfor,
];
   $rows[] = $array;

 return theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows));
    }
```

If I put $form values above the foreach loop it does displays values at the top of the table but it shows empty values.

Also see my screen shot which is currently displaying the bottom, and I want to show this at the top:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

change `$rows` declaration by :

```
$header = array(t('Sr no'),t('Image'),t('Public Path'), t('Is Dir'),t('Status'));
$rows = array(0 => 'will be replaced by values');
```

[...]
And at the end modify :

```
$array = [
  $form['#prefix'] = '<div class="page_summary" <strong>Summary: </strong>',
  $form['#prefix'] = '<div class="total_find" <strong>Total Find: </strong>'. $totalFind,
  $form['#prefix'] = '<div class="total_dir" <strong>Total Find: </strong>'. $totalIsDir,
  $form['#prefix'] = '<div class="total_should_resolve" <strong>Total Should Resolve</strong>: ' . $totalShouldFind.'<strong> / Total Resolved : </strong>'. $totalResolved,
  $form['#prefix'] = '<div class="error_bar" style="display">404:'.$forOfor,
];
   $rows[0] = $array;
```

Comment: Hey @Fky I did not understand $rows = array(0 => 'will be replaced by values'); which values? That I am passing in foreach?

Comment: are you there can you guide me .

Comment: $rows = array(0 => null); it's the same it's just to init first values into array , so next when you are using $rows=[] index will be 1 , 2 , etc... so after yours loops , you'll insert à 0 index total sum to place it on the first line of the array